# Placing numbers $1,2,...,7$ on an infinite square grid with constraint on each $3 \times 3$ block

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there is an infinite tile space (like infinitely large chess board). On each tile, I'm going to write a number among $1,2,...,7$. The question is

> Is there a possible numbering on each tile on infinite tile space so that every time I look $3\times 3$ block, all numbers $1$ to $7$ appear on the boundary $8$ tiles ?

My conjecture is No since I tried some examples but all failed. But I don't know how to prove. Could you help?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order it is more attractive. Do you agree ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Cool. It's more informative. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the origin of the problem ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible.

We'll number the tiles with $(i, j)$ with $i, j \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Suppose we fill the tile $(i, j)$ with number $i + j + 2\lfloor j/2 \rfloor$ for every integer $i$ and $j$.

**Claim.** For any $3 \times 3$ block of tiles centred in tile $(i, j)$, the eight numbers in the boundary consist of seven consecutive integers (and a duplicate).

**Proof.** We consider two cases.

- If $j = 2k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then the boundary tiles are

  - $(i-1, 2k)$, with number $(i-1) + 2k + 2k = i + 4k - 1$,
  - $(i-1, 2k+1)$, with number $(i-1) + (2k+1) + 2k = i + 4k$,
  - $(i-1, 2k+2)$, with number $(i-1) + (2k+2) + (2k+2) = i + 4k + 3$,
  - $(i, 2k)$, with number $i + 2k + 2k = i + 4k$,
  - $(i, 2k+2)$, with number $i + (2k+2) + (2k+2) = i + 4k + 4$,
  - $(i+1, 2k)$, with number $(i+1) + 2k + 2k = i + 4k + 1$,
  - $(i+1, 2k+1)$, with number $(i+1) + (2k+1) + 2k = i + 4k + 2$,
  - $(i+1, 2k+2)$, with number $(i+1) + (2k+2) + (2k+2) = i + 4k + 5$.

  So, the numbers in the boundaries are the seven integers from $i + 4k - 1$ to $i + 4k + 5$ (with one duplicate $i + 4k$).
- If $j = 2k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then the boundary tiles are

  - $(i-1, 2k-1)$, with number $(i-1) + (2k-1) + (2k-2) = i + 4k - 4$,
  - $(i-1, 2k)$, with number $(i-1) + 2k + 2k = i + 4k - 1$,
  - $(i-1, 2k+1)$, with number $(i-1) + (2k+1) + 2k = i + 4k$,
  - $(i, 2k-1)$, with number $i + (2k-1) + (2k-2) = i + 4k - 3$,
  - $(i, 2k+1)$, with number $i + (2k+1) + 2k = i + 4k + 1$,
  - $(i+1, 2k-1)$, with number $(i+1) + (2k-1) + (2k-2) = i + 4k - 2$,
  - $(i+1, 2k)$, with number $(i+1) + 2k + 2k = i + 4k + 1$,
  - $(i+1, 2k+1)$, with number $(i+1) + (2k+1) + 2k = i + 4k + 2$.

  Here, the numbers in the boundaries are the seven integers from $i + 4k - 4$ to $i + 4k + 2$ (with one duplicate $i + 4k + 1$).

In either case, we know that the boundary tiles contains $7$ consecutive integers. $\square$

To complete the proof, we simply consider modulo $7$. It should be easy to finish the proof from here.

---

Here is a portion of a desired construction.

**Edit:** Added border lines to illustrate how the pattern repeats.
\begin{array}{|cccccccccccccc|cccccccccccccc|} \hline
1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5 \\
2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6 \\
3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7 \\
4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1 \\
5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2 \\
6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3 \\
7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4 \\ \hline
1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5 \\
2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6 \\
3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7 \\
4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1 \\
5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2 \\
6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3 \\
7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4&7&1&4&5&1&2&5&6&2&3&6&7&3&4 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Cool! How did you came up with that formula $i+j+2\lfloor j/2\rfloor$?

Comment: Guesswork. I wrote the first four columns and figured that $i + j + 2\lfloor j/2 \rfloor$ perfectly describes those four columns. (How to describe the sequence $1, 2, 5, 6$? I thought a floor/ceiling operation would be needed.) Then I wrote the next columns to see if it works. After confirming it works, I then tried finding a rigorous proof.

Comment: A comment : the grid is of type $\mathbb{N \times N}$, not $\mathbb{Z \times Z}$. Indeed, your grid cannot be extended for example to the left while fulfilling the conditions.

Comment: @JeanMarie Why not? The grid above is actually already composed of four identical subtiles (with 7 rows and 14 columns),

Comment: You are right: I am convinced with your new presentation. A little detail : the word "subtile" is not appropriate (it would mean a tile breaking): "block of tiles" would be appropriate.

Comment: @JeanMarie That makes sense; I was just following the original word used in the question.

Comment: I have already updated your very very good answer.